# RaspberryPi Kernel command line has no effect

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, debian-jessie

I'm using the latest DietPi image on a RaspberryPi.

In spite of the /boot/cmdline.txt:

```
# cat cmdline.txt 
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=XYZXYZ rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

The actual command line uses the ttyAMA0 serial port:

```
# dmesg | more
...
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1280 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=720 bcm2708_fb.fbdepth=16 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=x:x:x:x:x:x vc_mem.mem_base=0 x1fa00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=XYZXYZ rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

How can I change the command line parameters to NOT use the ttyAMA0 for the system messages?

Comment: Okay, I now know that "serial0" gets translated to ttyAMA0 at some point upon boot. Might be interesting to see where is it getting translated though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what distro/build you're using, you may also have something else tacking on kernel command line args after the fact. In my case, I needed add an environmental variable change in armbianEnv.txt:
console=display

The armbianEnv.txt file should be placed in whichever directory contains your boot.cmd file. It could boot /boot, or like for my BPI-P2 Zero it was /boot/bananapi/bpi-m2z/linux